# Laravel is not accepting the CSS- the CSS is only partially displayed

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

This is the CSS that I was trying to insert in the head:

```
<!-- GOOGLE-FONTS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,700" >

<!-- OTHER FONTS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{HTML::style('assets/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" >

<!-- ANIMATED -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  id="animationcss" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/animation.css')}}" >

<!-- BOOTSTRAP-CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.css')}}" >

<!--  CUSTOM -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/style.css')}}" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/custom-scrollbar.css')}}">

<!-- BUTTONCOLORS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/colors/red.css')}}">

<!-- RESPONSIVE-STYLES -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/responsive.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/colors/red-responsive.css')}}">
<!-- FAVICON -->

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{URL::asset('assets/img/favicon.png')}}" >
```

The problem is that when I open the website, it will not show red.css, nor fontawesome icons nor any other things. It will ONLY accept style.css (from the Google Chrome inspect tool)

What is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: In my own experience this kind of problems are related to caching, in server by apache or in the client by the browser. Did you try to restart your apache or local web server or clear the cache of your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Change this link

```
<!-- OTHER FONTS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{HTML::style('assets/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" >
```

to either

```
{{HTML::style('assets/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}
```

or

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" >
```